# Subtract int from char : possible lossy conversion int to char

Tags: java, types

I am trying to subtract int from char in a typical cryptography key question but I am running into the above mentioned error in the following statements:

```
char ch = (int)encrypted_message.charAt(i) + key[index];
if (ch > 122)
    ch = (int)ch - 26;
```

`key[]` array holds digits of the key and is of type `int`.

How do rotate the char successfully?

Please help!

Comment: What is your question? If you try to fit a 32-bit datatype into a 16-bit datatype, there is the risk of lost information. Note that all arithmeitc operations in Java will always yield at least an `int` since there are no primitives for `boolean`, `byte`, `char` and `short` in the JVM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int` is bigger than `char`, but the result of your operation is typed `int` (which you're then storing in a `char`). So the compiler is warning you you might lose information storing an `int` value into a `char` variable.

Instead, ensure the result is a `char`, which is a bit of a pain because `+` and `-` with `char` values results in an `int`, so we have to cast:

```
char ch = (char)(encrypted_message.charAt(i) + key[index]);
if (ch > 122)
    ch = (char)(ch - 26);
```