# I don't understand why I get the compiler error "Lossy conversion from int to short"

Tags: java, integer, short

For this code:

```
  public class Solution{
       public static void main(String[] args){
                     short x = 10;
                     x =  x * 5;
                     System.out.print(x);
       }
    }
```

This will give compile error - “Lossy conversion from int to short”

Why? Short has a maximum value of 32,767, 10 * 5 = 50, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: I did add the tag, it went, had to add it again. So why is 5 an int and not a short? I mean, 5 can also be a short. Or does the compiler just assume its an int? @KenWhite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment char variable by an int value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374896/increment-char-variable-by-an-int-value)

Comment: a literal is int by default if it's in int's range, and operations are int-promoted. It's the same as other C-like languages. Duplicates: [incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55322896/995714), [Inconsistent "possible lossy conversion from int to byte" compile-time error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56162939/995714), [Subtract int from char : possible lossy conversion int to char](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40534091/995714)

Comment: Only int, long, float, and double values may be multiplied.  `x * 5` forces `x` to be an int, and the result is an int.  The compiler only compiles code;  it doesn’t run the code and it doesn’t have the ability to keep track of the value of `x` in a program, so it doesn’t know that `x` will be 10 when that line executes.

Comment: It'll work if you do `x *= 5`

Answer (score 1):

When you do calculations with short, byte or char Java automatically converts them to int and return int result so you should has to use casting. `x = (short) (x*5)`